# JQuery - selecting dynamically named elements to use in equations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a question that I'm stumped on. I'm building a form that has input fields that are then used in equations. However, the tricky part is that I have additional fieldsets and inputs dynamically created and named (so that when the user clicks "Add New Fence" there is a second "postQuantity" named "postQuantity2" and then the third would be called "postQuantity3" etc). My question is how can I change my existing equation to select the elements only for its specific section (each individual fence that is added) of the form? 
For example: When I type into footage2 then it would use that input in the JS equation and plug the answer into postQuantity2, and then footage3 with postQuantity3, etc.Any ideas would be greatly appreciated because I don't know where to start on this one.

Here is a snippet of what I have so far:
Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/QGW7R/

Html:

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div id="inputFence1" class="clonedInputFence">
        <fieldset id="fenceDescripton">
            <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>

            </legend>
            <label>Footage:
            <input type="number" id="footage" name="footage" value="" /></label>
            <select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
                <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
                <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
                <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="post">
            <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>

            </legend>

            <label>Post Quantity:
                <input type="postQuantity" name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="postMeasurements" id="postMeasurements">
                <option value="select">Select Post Measurements</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .065 x 8" id="23/8 x .065 x 8">2 3/8 x .065 x 8</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .095 x 8" id="23/8 x .095 x 8">23/8 x .095 x 8</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
//Quantity for Posts
    $('#footage, #manualOverrideNo').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){

            var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
            var total = '';

            if(!isNaN(footage)){
                total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
                $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
            } else {
                $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val("");
            }
    });

//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
    $('#btnAddFence').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#inputFence' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputFence' + newNum);

                //Fieldset creation
                newElem.find('fieldset').attr('id', 'fence' + newNum);

                //Fence Description 
                newElem.find("select[name=fenceHeight]").attr('id', 'fenceHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'fenceHeight' + newNum);
                newElem.find(':input[name="footage"]').attr('id', 'footage' + newNum).attr('name', 'footage' + newNum);

                //Post Type
                newElem.find(':input[name="postQuantity"]').attr('id', 'postQuantity' + newNum).attr('name', 'postQuantity' + newNum);
                newElem.find("select[name=postMeasurements]").attr('id', 'postMeasurements' + newNum).attr('name', 'postMeasurements' + newNum);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
                $('#inputFence' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button
                //$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#inputFence' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAddFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dynamically create the elements, you could group sets of fields by index and associate it with the fields:

```
newElem.data('index', currentIndex);
```

When you update values, you can then use this index to update the appropriate field within the same set of fields:

```
$field = $(event.target).closest(':input[name="footage"]'); // event.target is the element that first registered the event
index = $($field).data('index');
...
$(':input[name="postQuantity"][data-index="' + index + '"]').val(total.toString());
```

You can grab the event object in the event handler:

```
$(...).bind(..., function(event) {
```

Comment: Having a little trouble wrapping my head around this one. I'm playing around with it but not a 100% on how this is going to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah I can't get it to work lol. Could you elaborate a little more about how these blocks of code are supposed to be plugged in, because using them as I thought best didn't work.

Comment: @gv0029 Oops, try using `newElem.find(':input[name="footage"]').data('index', yourIndex)` instead. Basically, you want to associate an index value to an element that you can later pick up when the user interacts with the field. In your event handler, it will be passed an event object that has `.target`, `.currentTarget`, etc. `.target` should be whatever element the event was triggered on. You don't have `#footage` and other elements in your example, so it may also be necessary to bind the handler to a different element.